# Rails 4 SSL error stops direct s3 upload with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've been following [this guide](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) on doing direct to S3 uploads with paperclip as well as [this blog post](http://dja.roon.io/rails-4-multiple-image-file-uploads-with-paperclip-s3-direct-upload) that suggests some useful tweaks to the previously linked guide. My only difference is the name of my model which is photos as opposed to documents.

I'm getting the original file to successfully upload to my bucket but the before_create action in photo.rb (document.rb in the guide) fails at this line:

```
direct_upload_head = s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]].objects[direct_upload_url_data[:path]].head
```

the rails server console shows the following error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname does not match the server certificate):
>     app/models/photo.rb:56:in `set_upload_attributes'

I was previously getting errors relating to the DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT validation failing due to incorrect formatting so I modified that slightly to match the direct_upload_url being generated by paperclip. My modified version is:

```
DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT = %r{\Ahttps:\/\/#{Rails.configuration.aws[:region]}\.amazonaws\.com\/#{Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]}\/(?<path>uploads\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze
```

This matches the format of the url being shown in the console:

> "photo"=>{"direct_upload_url"=>"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/uploads%2F1389613985667-mo4ncxxus0q0vn29-d78ac9dc4f18fa612e33c87ec9ad0f4e%2Fmiddy.jpg"}

It was after modifying DIRECT_UPLOAD_URL_FORMAT that I got it to pass the validation and the SSL error came up.

I've noticed that in the url shown in the console as the one being posted the forward slashes aren't showing after 'uploads' and the folder name but they do up until then. Could this have something to do with it not meeting the SSL requirements?

All the other code matches what is in the guide except for 'documents' switched to 'photos' where necessary.

Is there anything I can do to meet the SSL requirements?

edit:
I should also mention that where I've put 'mybucketname' in the quoted url my actual bucket name matches that format with no dots or dashes etc., just lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my problems were caused by the region I had selected for my bucket.

The tutorial is set up for using path style URLs which only work in the US Standard region.

I had chosen an EU region (Ireland) for my development bucket and was unsuccessful in modifying the code to make use of the domain style URLs required for non US Standard buckets.

I found the info in Amazon's docs under the heading 'Bucket Access':
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LocationSelection.html

I'm satisfied with how my code works now but will continue to look at how I can modify it to use the Ireland bucket region to reduce latency during development.